# YUI Shifter builder for language i18n from YRB(.pres)

Tags: javascript, internationalization, yui, yui3

I am working on website internalization and it has YUI3 in stack, so it is good to use YUI intl module for that. Reading [documentation](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/intl/#externalizing) gave idea to leverage shifter builder to convert Java property i18n files into YUI3 intl format (think as YRB(.pres) as they both have same syntax. Going from that I created meta `module/meta/module.json` file looking like this:

```
{
  "modulename": {
    "requires": [
        "oop"
    ]
},
"lang": ["en"]
}
```

And accordingly placed the language file like `module/lang/modulename_en.pres`.

That's not worked out, build processing successfully but no lang folders with context created. Also I tried use json like javascript version with no luck. I guess missing some additional step.

UPD: Thank you for comments. There is wrong syntax in my meta, the `lang` property has to be on the same level as `requires` that fixed problem with finding language files but still there is error when trying to use .pres files. Here it is the output:

```
....
shifter [info] shifting 2 langs for module

fs.js:427
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'c:\\..\module\lang\module.js'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
    at Object.fs.openSync (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\shifter\node_mod
ules\cpr\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:68:26)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:284:15)
    at c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\shifter\lib\module.js:424:26
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.buildLang [as lang] (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\shifter\
lib\module.js:417:11)
    at c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\shifter\lib\module.js:709:33
    at c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\shifter\lib\stack.js:24:38
    at c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\shifter\lib\module.js:372:13
    at c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\shifter\node_modules\gear\node_modul
es\async\lib\async.js:190:13
```

I also opened report into [shifter github repo](https://github.com/yui/shifter/issues/94). Will try to debug and see what I am missing here.

Comment: Also asked in: https://github.com/yui/shifter/issues/94

Comment: The `lang` property in the sample json file above should be nested at the same level as the `requires`, but I assume that might be a copying error.

Comment: Meta file is good, I probably had some name inconsistences, anyway I have now lang modules generated from .js but have error when trying use .pres. Still exploring.

Comment: Oh, yes you was right about nesting, that's was a blocker (no errors by the way), but still trying to make .pres run around.

Comment: Clearly, shifter expects only .js files:  https://github.com/yui/shifter/blob/master/lib/module.js#L423

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like intl module documentation is referring for some other internal version of shifter other than git one, or possibly that functionality is on its  way. Nevertheles I needed that functionality and there is what [works so far](https://github.com/dmi3y/shifter/tree/lang-support-pres).

UPD: Thanks for comment I did glimpse to pre shifter era builder, and find out yrb2json parser [here](https://github.com/yui/builder/blob/master/componentbuild/lib/yrb2json/yrb2json.js) in already javascript format. Seems I am only the one person for these years who was interested in this functionality into nodejs shifter.

Comment: Initially YUI was built using an ant-based built system.  Shifter came after that user guide was written.  The earlier built system probably handled the .pres files while shifter never got to do that.